# Angular 7-how to download txt file from file protocol

Tags: angular

I am sure there is no direct way to download from file protocol like file://abc.cmp.com/folder/xyz.txt,so I tried to get file using httpClient ,converting to blob and then downloading.
But this also not working and getting error like below:

```
zone.js:3243 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file://abc.cmp.com/folder/xyz.txt' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

Sample code:

sample.html

```html
<td><a [routerLink] = [] (click)="download('file://abc.cmp.com/folder/xyz.txt')">file://abc.cmp.com/folder/xyz.txt')</a></td>
```

sample.component.ts:

```js
    download(url){
        let  a = document.createElement("a");
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        let data  = this.sampleService.getFileContent(url);
        let file = new Blob(data, {type:'text/plain'});
          let fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
          a.href = fileURL;
          a.download = 'log';
          a.click();
      }
```

sample.service.ts:

```js
    getFileContent(url) {
        return this.httpClient.get(url)
            .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
      }
```

It would be great if there is a way to handle this.

Comment: When you open the url in new tab it is downloading as expected?

Comment: No its not downloading.Instead loading same page.

Comment: The web uses the http protocol. file is for loading **local** files (i.e. files on the client machine), but you can't do that for security reasons anyway.

Comment: use of wrong protocol  in the url `file:/// ` is the issue here

Comment: No Its my typo.

Comment: @JBNizet No other way to do download the file?

Comment: Or atleast can we able to view the file?

Comment: Why won't you include this file in your assets folder, and serve it statically?

Comment: No I want it dynamically. Those file are in common places